# XSLT copy text before childs and transform childs

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to take this XML

```
<tag>text before childs
    <child1 attr="value"/>
    <child2 attr="value"/>
    text after childs
</tag>
```

I have a template for `child1` and `child2` that looks like this

```
<xsl:template match="child1">
    GOOFY
</xsl:template>
```

and

```
<xsl:template match="child2">
    DONALDDUCK
</xsl:template>
```

I want to transform the XML in something like

```
<tag> 
  text before childs GOOFY DONALDDUCK text after childs  
</tag>
```

Following the advice of michael.hor257k I've tryied using an identity template like this

```
<xsl:template match="tag">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="child1"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="child2"/>
        </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

but as a result I get

```
<tag/>
```

or

```
<tag>GOOFY DONALDDUCK</tag>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? The two templates you already have, plus either a template matching `<tag>` or the *identity transform* template, should produce the result you're after (perhaps with some white space that needs to be stripped).

Comment: I'm not getting the point :)

Comment: Please post a **complete** stylesheet. It can be minimal, but make it complete, so that we can see what result you are getting now.

Comment: I've updated the question with an example stylesheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a complete stylesheet, and you're certainly **not** using the *identity transform* template. If your stylesheet looked like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="child1">
    GOOFY
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="child2">
    DONALDDUCK
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

then the result, applied to your input example, would have been:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tag>text before childs

    GOOFY


    DONALDDUCK

    text after childs
</tag>
```

Comment: Yeah the problem is that I'm doing XML stuff without knowing XML :) What if the real XML is far more complex than this one? Will the identity transform match all the nodes in the xml?

Comment: @AlessandroL. The [identity transform template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) is designed to copy *everything* as-is.